Can I give users the option between sending Cognito Verification Code through email or SMS?
I have a React App with AWS Amplify using Cognito for Authentication, currently I send a Verification code through the user's email but I want to give them the option to choose if they want to receive it through email or SMS and I haven't been able to find any info about if this is even possible.
The closest I've found is using email if phone number is not available, but that's not quite what I want to do.

Amazon Cognito uses Amazon SNS to send SMS message: Please have a look at this link if this helps: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-settings-email-phone-verification.html


Go to the AWS Сonsole.
Find and go to Cognito.
Next, select your User pool.
On the page, you need to find the Messaging tab
Try playing with the settings here screen

